# Android buttons background

Tags: java, android, android-button

I'm trying to make a Java-Android-Memory Game... Everything works fine, except from one thing... when you turn the first card, and then the second card, there should be some delay (~seconds or so) bevor the two cards are turned or removed.

So I added the delay (tried 2 versions, I now made them a comment)

But....  the picture of the card is never shown for the second card (only for the first card)...   the cards are removed or hidden with the correct delay when I use the second version.

pls. can someone help me

here the code (relevant part)

```
public abstract class Game {
private static final int maxButtonAmount = 30;  //maximum amount of buttons (=cards) per game

private Card[] cards;
private HashMap<Button, Card> buttonsToCardMap;

//the button of the first turned card, null if all cards are turned down
private Button firstTurnedCardButton;

private View.OnClickListener defaultListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        turnCard((Button) v);
        evaluateCardChoice((Button) v);
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener audioListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        GameActivity.sound.playCardMusic(GameActivity.getContext(), buttonsToCardMap.get(v).getResID());
    }
};



//------ GamePlay-Methods ------

protected abstract void endGame();

protected abstract void finishTurn(boolean foundPair);

/** Turns a card. If it is clickable the background is set to the appropriate drawable of that card and clickable will be set to false. <br><br>
 *
 * If it is not clickable (aka is turned) then the background will be set to R.drawable.cards_back and it will be made clickable again.
 *
 * @param turnedCardButton The button of the card to turn.
 */
private void turnCard(Button turnedCardButton){
    Card card = buttonsToCardMap.get(turnedCardButton);
    if (card.getCardState().equals(CardState.HIDDEN)){
        card.setCardState(CardState.TURNED);
        Log.d("testlog", "card turned");
        if (card.getCardType().equals(CardType.PICTURE)){
            turnedCardButton.setBackgroundResource(card.getResID());
            turnedCardButton.setClickable(false);
        }
        else{
            turnedCardButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cards_audio);
            GameActivity.sound.playCardMusic(GameActivity.getContext(), card.getResID());
            turnedCardButton.setOnClickListener(audioListener);
        }
    }
    else{
        card.setCardState(CardState.HIDDEN);
        Log.d("testlog","card hidden");
        turnedCardButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cards_back);
        if (card.getCardType().equals(CardType.PICTURE)){
            turnedCardButton.setClickable(true);
        }
        else{
            turnedCardButton.setOnClickListener(defaultListener);
        }
    }
}

private void evaluateCardChoice(Button turnedCardButton){
    /*
    //give the user time to see the card before evaluation
    try{
        Log.d("testlog", "waiting...");
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
        Log.e("testlog", "InterruptedException in Game.initialiseButtons");
    }
    */
    /*
       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
       long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
       Log.d("testlog", "waiting...");
       while( (now-start)<3000){
           now=System.currentTimeMillis();
       }
       start= System.currentTimeMillis();
       Log.d("testlog", "stopped waiting...");
     */




    //if no card is turned yet then save this button as the first turned card, otherwise check for a found pair
    if (firstTurnedCardButton == null){
        firstTurnedCardButton = turnedCardButton;
    }
    else{
        if (buttonsToCardMap.get(firstTurnedCardButton).matches(buttonsToCardMap.get(turnedCardButton))){
            firstTurnedCardButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            buttonsToCardMap.get(firstTurnedCardButton).setCardState(CardState.COLLECTED);
            turnedCardButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            buttonsToCardMap.get(turnedCardButton).setCardState(CardState.COLLECTED);

            firstTurnedCardButton = null;
            this.finishTurn(true);
            if (!moreCardsAvailable()){
                endGame();
            }
        }
        else {
            turnCard(firstTurnedCardButton);
            turnCard(turnedCardButton);

            firstTurnedCardButton = null;
            this.finishTurn(false);
        }
    }
}

private boolean moreCardsAvailable(){
    boolean moreCards = false;

    for (Card c : cards){
        if (!c.getCardState().equals(CardState.COLLECTED)){
            moreCards = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return moreCards;
}

//------ Initialization-Methods ------

private void initialiseCardsArray(String cardSetName, boolean onlyPictures){
    ArrayList<Integer> pictureResIds = Card.getResourceIDsFromCardSet(cardSetName, "drawable");
    ArrayList<Integer> audioResIds = Card.getResourceIDsFromCardSet(cardSetName, "raw");

    ArrayList<Integer> pairIDs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < pictureResIds.size(); i++){
        pairIDs.add(i);
    }

    //choose random cards from the cardSet and add them to cards
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i += 2){
        int pairID = pairIDs.remove(new Random().nextInt(pairIDs.size()));
        cards[i] = new PictureCard(pairID, pictureResIds.get(pairID));
        if (onlyPictures) { cards[i+1] = new PictureCard(pairID, pictureResIds.get(pairID)); }
        else { cards[i+1] = new AudioCard(pairID, audioResIds.get(pairID)); }
    }
}

private void initialiseButtons(){
    //create a list to randomly draw indexes from cards
    ArrayList<Integer> cardIndexList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
        cardIndexList.add(i);
    }

    //initializes the used buttons and deletes all the other buttons
    for (int i = 0; i < maxButtonAmount; i++){
        if (i < cards.length){
            int buttonResID = GameActivity.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(String.format("btn_card%02d", i), "id", GameActivity.getContext().getPackageName());
            Button curBtn = (Button) ((Activity) GameActivity.getContext()).findViewById(buttonResID);
            curBtn.setOnClickListener(defaultListener);
            curBtn.setText("");
            curBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cards_back);
            //choose random index from cards and map it to curBtn
            buttonsToCardMap.put(curBtn, cards[cardIndexList.remove(new Random().nextInt(cardIndexList.size()))]);
        }
        else{
            int buttonResID = GameActivity.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(String.format("btn_card%02d", i), "id", GameActivity.getContext().getPackageName());
            ((Activity) GameActivity.getContext()).findViewById(buttonResID).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}

private void positionButtons(){
    Button[] buttons = buttonsToCardMap.keySet().toArray(new Button[cards.length]);
    int colAmount = getButtonColumnAmount();
    int rowAmount = (int) Math.ceil(cards.length/colAmount);
    int btnHeight = calculateButtonHeight(rowAmount);
    int btnWidth = (int) Math.floor(btnHeight*0.7711);
    int btnXMargin = (GameActivity.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels - (colAmount * btnWidth))/(colAmount+1);
    // TODO int btnYMargin = (GameActivity.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - (rowAmount * btnHeight))/(rowAmount+1);

    int curBtnIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowAmount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colAmount && curBtnIndex < buttons.length; j++) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.leftMargin = j*btnWidth + (j+1)*btnXMargin; //x-coord
            params.topMargin = i*btnHeight ; //y-coord TODO + (i+1)*btnYMargin;
            params.width = btnWidth;        //width
            params.height = btnHeight;      //height
            buttons[curBtnIndex].setLayoutParams(params);

            curBtnIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already found a solution... I now use a Handler to change the background